# Neo4j, get specific relationships between a set of nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have one set of node node1 and node2

```
(node1) <- rel1 - (node2)
(node1) <- rel2 - (node2)
(node1) <- rel3 - (node2)
(node1) <- rel4 - (node2)
```

I can get all type of relations between them by

```
MATCH (a:node1) -[r] - (b:node2) RETURN DISTINCT a, b
```

Now I only want rel1 and rel2 between these nodes

How i can achive this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its working like this

```
MATCH (a:node1) <-[:rel2 | :rel1] - (b:node2) RETURN DISTINCT a, b
```